# GWT: PushButton is not removing hovering if the click opens dialog

Tags: events, gwt

I've got a simple GWT PushButton which opens some dialog by click. The CSS styles are written in such a way that onHovering changes the appearance of the button.

**The problem starts when I open some dialog by clicking on this button and close it. The onHovering styles remain!**

This happens because in the CustomButtom which is the parent of PushButton there is a code which removes the hovering only when MouseOut event occurs. The problem is that if you open dialog with some dark semi-transparent screen it never occurs. The corresponding event is not issued and the button remains in onHovered state.

**I try to fix this by firing this event manually.** Fortunately, when the user closes that dialog I can catch onBlur event and try to do something in that moment. I try to create OnMouseOut event manually:

```
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {

        int type = DOM.eventGetType(event);
        if (type == Event.ONBLUR)
        {
            NativeEvent evt2 = Document.get().createMouseOutEvent(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, NativeEvent.BUTTON_LEFT, MyPushButton.this.getElement());
            MyPushButton.this.getElement().dispatchEvent(evt2);
        }

        logger.info(event.getType());

        super.onBrowserEvent(event);
    }
```

... but for some reasons this code never sends an event. New MouseOut event is not logged in console and the onHovering styles are not changed. No exceptions are thrown.

Why I cannot fire the event?
Is there other ways to solve this issue?

GWT 2.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2228

Actually, there are [several issues with *custom buttons*](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/list?can=1&q=PushButton%20status%3aNew,Accepted,PatchesWelcome,NotPlanned,AssumedStale,Started,ReviewPending,NeedsInfo), and you're encouraged to use `Button` (or `SubmitButton` or `ResetButton`) and CSS if possible; or maybe `TextButton` (or a custom cell-based `ButtonBase` subclass).
`ToggleButton` might be an exception as it has no real equivalent, other than a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've made it working. Please notice Thomas Broyer's answer which is more broad.

```
@Override
/**
 * In case onClick opens dialog, mouseOutEvent is not issued, thus preventing the button
 * from removing the onHovering styles. Firing that event manually onBlur.
 */
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event)
{
    if (DOM.eventGetType(event) == Event.ONBLUR)
    {
        NativeEvent mouseOutEvent = Document.get().createMouseOutEvent(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, NativeEvent.BUTTON_LEFT, getElement().getParentElement());
        getElement().dispatchEvent(mouseOutEvent);
        super.onBrowserEvent(Event.as(mouseOutEvent));
    }
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);
}
```